# Most of the Iterators and Iterables methods are LAZY! What does this mean

Tags: java, collections, iterator, guava

1 of the presentation says "These methods are LAZY!"

```
Iterable transform(Iterable, Function)*
Iterable filter(Iterable, Predicate)*
T find(Iterable<T>, Predicate)
Iterable concat(Iterable<Iterable>)
Iterable cycle(Iterable)
T getOnlyElement(Iterable<T>)
Iterable<T> reverse(List<T>)
```

Can someone help me understand what they mean by this, lets say I've a collection of `Persons` and I apply a filter to return only the persons whose last name is DOE.

So does this mean that the "filtering happens only on the first call to doeOnly.next()?"

```
List<Person> persons= ....
Iterable doeOnly= Iterables.filter(persons,DOE_AS_LAST_NAME_PREDICATE);
```

Comment: Filtering must happen on the first call to `doeOnly.hasNext()` not `next()`, because if there is only one element remaining but it fails the predicate then `hasNext()` must return false, but the filter does not know that until it has fetched the non-matching element.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It means that the data is filtered as you request it - it doesn't go through your list immediately, and build up a new list of the filtered data. Instead, when you call `iterator.next()` (e.g. automatically in an enhanced for loop) the iterator will ask its upstream data source (your collection) for the next data item. It will then try to match this against the filter. If it matches it, it'll return that item. Otherwise, it'll ask for another item from the collection, keeping going until it either runs out of items or finds a match.

Then when you *next* ask for the next item, it'll keep going from where it left off.

In other words, it doesn't just mean "filtering happens only on the first call to `doeOnly.next()`" - it means "filtering happens on *each* call to `iterator.next()`" where `iterator` is the result of calling `doeOnly.iterator()`.

Comment: thx for both the responses...also does google-collect use applicative or delayed evaluation

Comment: i understood the laziness in filter and other methods as they return Iterable...but how can be explain the laziness w.r.t find and getOnlyElement

Comment: @Pangea: I suspect those shouldn't be documented as being lazy.

Comment: But those methods *are* lazy!  They do no work until they absolutely have to.  It just happens to be right away that they have to. :)